# Difference in Code Coverage% after upgrading from Sonar 3.4.1 to Sonarqube 4.3.2

Tags: sonarqube

I have recently upgraded Sonar from Version 3.4.1 to Sonarqube 4.3.2. I am using Cobertura version 1.6.2 and Java plugin 2.3 in Sonar.The Unit Tests Success% is same that is 100% in both the cases but there is difference in the Code Coverage% being displayed (Earlier it was 22.7% and now in Sonarqube 4.3.2,it is 15.9%).The difference is significant.Also there is difference in the Lines of Code after upgradation (Earlier it was 1,906 and after upgradation it is 2,704).Anyone having idea that what can be the reason for this difference.
Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still facing this issue.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have you have analysis/coverage exclusions activated on your 3.4.1 instance but not on your 4.3.2 instance. This would explain the coverage difference / lines difference.

Check in globlal settings and project settings :

- Global Source File exclusions
- Source File exclusions
- Jacoco excludes

Answer (score 0):

We had the exclusions mentioned in pom.xml but in 4.3.2 version we came to know it needs to be specified on Sonar UI under •Global Source File exclusions
 or Source File exclusions.but this didn't work either for LoC.